# Unity generates changes in GitHub on saving scene

Tags: unity, git

So, here is my problem.

First I have a look at the changes in the repository which I am working with.

Initially there are no changes:

[image]

Then I open up Unity, i don't make any changes and just save the scene:

[image]

I then go to GitHub Desktop and suddenly there are a lot of changes appearing which I did not make:

[image]

How can I avoid that?

The files which are getting changed are `.prefab` files.

[image]

Comment: Have you committed and fetched at least once?

Comment: @GabrieleVierti, yes I did.

Comment: @GabrieleVierti, every time I need to commit I have to go through all that unnecessary changes and chose and commit only those that were generated by me.

Comment: @GabrieleVierti, and there are seems to appear more and more changes after saving scene. I mean every time I commit then the next time I save scene there a few more unknown changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Those changes <s>seem to be of `.meta` file contents, and/or scene stuff</s> <sup><sub>[**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, they seem to be prefab data. But the issue and solution are the same]</sub></sup>. It's not unthinkable that some floats will have the least significant bits changed due to floating-point precision errors. You can just ignore the fact that those changes exist, and commit them.

---

**Slightly longer answer:**

Don't worry... A `position` or `rotation` changed by `1e-6` (`0.000001`; BTW, yours are, like, `1e-12+` [`0.000000000001`]) is not going to have any noticeable difference in most games (in fact, unity considers anything with difference under `1e-5` as "equal", if you look at the source code). Your game would need to be a game like KSP trying to shoot something across the solar-system to hit a relatively tiny target in order for those to make a noticeable difference. =D

---

**Bonus:**

Since you seem to be unaware of the concept of FPPEs (floating-point precision errors), I will ***strongly*** recommend you to take a look at [**What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic**](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: I would not commit those because they'll clutter up the history and make it harder to spot the real changes.

Comment: @immibis Well, you don't get much of a choice; `.meta` files are necessary for the project to work correctly, AFAIK; not committing those would mean that your remote repo does not represent the same as your local repo(s), breaking the primary purpose of having version-control in the first place, and then, even if that wasn't the case, it would give you hell later and/or when working on teams. This is why, basically, all VCS tutorials on unity tell you to configure unity so that it makes `.meta` files plain-text, so that VCS can work with them easily (because you ***need*** to commit them).

Comment: You don't commit files, you commit changes. I would not commit those changes. The specific changes mentioned in the question are: moving object positions on the order of 10^-6.

Comment: @immibis I meant that you can't `.ignore` the files, and exactly because the changes are *`1e-6`*, and will have no noticeable result in-game, you're better off just committing them. --- If you want to ***waste effort*** on reviewing which changes to commit and which not to, I can't understand the logic in that, but do whatever you feel like.  (BTW, about "moving objects in the order of `1e-6`, that's not the question, that's my answer)

Comment: I'd rather not ***waste effort*** resolving merge conflicts where I moved the objects by 1e-6 but someone else actually moved them. Or ***waste effort*** sifting through all of my commits to find the last time the objects were actually moved. When using Git on a team, I always review and select which changes to commit. `git add -p` makes it pretty straightforward to do.

Comment: @immibis So you prefer to trade merge conflicts that are done for you automatically, and that *should be there because they actually happen*; and which you can easily filter through when you need to "find the last time the objects were actually moved", for slow and error-prone human reviewing that will, sooner or later, result in not committing an actual move because you unchecked the wrong checkbox. Cool. 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69680/discussion-between-immibis-and-xenoro).

Comment: Oh. Actually those are `.prefabs`, but not `.meta`. Have a look at the question, please. I will update it. Help me if you know how to prevent this, please.

Comment: @immibis, Oh. Actually those are `.prefabs`, but not `.meta`. Have a look at the question, please. I will update it. Help me if you know how to prevent this, please.

Comment: @trafalgarLaww Irrelevant in regards to the core of the issue and the solution, but thanks still. I have updated to answer to point primarily to that instead of `.meta` files. =)

Comment: I do not see a solution actually...

Comment: @trafalgarLaww Sometimes the solution to the issue is that there is none solution to what causes the issue, and that you just have to go with it. That's the point of my answer. Unity will reevaluate and change those floats every time it loads/saves the project; in the process, introducing FPPEs; those changes by FPPEs aren't going away, so you have basically two ways of dealing with it: Either you filter them every time before commit (immibis' idea of how it should be done), or you filter them only when you need to after the fact (my way). Pros and Cons were already discussed; pick one. 